# iOS app with bluetooth as a trigger

Tags: ios, bluetooth, location, proximity

I'm trying to help produce a location-specific iOS app that needs an external trigger to start audio playback when it approaches a given location within the building. (no GPS access)

Has anyone had experience doing something similar? One thought I had was to lay out some bluetooth "transmitters" (like an xbee+arduino) around the building, and if the iPhone's bluetooth was close enough to identify it, it would trigger the audio.

I've never worked with bluetooth or an application of this sort before, so any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Bluetooth would certainly work, although other methods might, too. The only downside to Bluetooth is that you would either need to work within the APple MFi program for standard Bluetooth or restrict the devices used to the iPhone 4s or later or the iPad 3rd Generation or later so you could use Bluetooth LE (Bluetooth 4.0).

Assuming you can use Bluetooth LE, it's not only possible, Apple demoed one such technology. Once you're signed up as a developer, check out Session 705, Advanced Core Bluetooth, from WWDC 2012. The ending demo is exactly what you're looking for, and the session describes how to do it and provides source code.

Comment: do you know if that source code can be found online? thank you.

Comment: You can find Bluetooth LE code in techBASIC at here: http://www.byteworks.us/Byte_Works/Blog/Entries/2012/8/20_Controlling_Bluetooth_LE_Devices_with_techBASIC.html.

Comment: Apple has an example here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/HeartRateMonitor/Listings/HeartRateMonitor_HeartRateMonitorAppDelegate_m.html